# DataStax Enterprise: Spark Cassandra Batch Size

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I set the parameter spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows in my SparkConf as following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "host")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")            
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
        .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "5120")
        .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "10")
```

but when i perform

> saveToCassandra("data","ten_days")

I continue to see warning in my system.log

```
NFO [FlushWriter:7] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,498 Memtable.java (line 395) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/hints/system-hints-jb-76-Data.db (5747287 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1416480663951, position=44882909)
 INFO [FlushWriter:7] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,499 Memtable.java (line 355) Writing Memtable-ten_days@1656582530(32979978/329799780 serialized/live bytes, 551793 ops)
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:761] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,499 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36825, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31705.
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:777] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,500 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36813, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31693.
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:822] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,501 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36823, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31703.
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:835] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,500 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36817, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31697.
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:781] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,501 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36817, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31697.
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:755] 2014-11-20 11:11:16,501 BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [data.ten_days] is of size 36822, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 31702.
```

I know that are only warnings, but I would like to understand why my settings aren't working as expected. Then I can see a lot of hints in my cluster. Could the batch size affects the number of hints in the cluster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set batch size rows instead of batch size bytes. This means the connector is limiting on the amount of rows rather than the memory size of the batch.

> spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows: number of rows per single
> batch; default is 'auto' which means the connector will adjust the
> number of rows based on the amount of data in each row
>
> spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes: maximum total size of the
> batch in bytes; defaults to 64 kB.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md

On a more important note you are most likely going to be better off with a larger batch size (64kb) and changing the warn limit in the cassandra.yaml file.

## Edit:

Recently we've seen that larger batches can cause instability with certain C* configurations so lower the value if the system becomes unstable.

Comment: sir I have similar problem while writing of 204 million records into cassandra it is taking 24hours , me simply getting data frame from oracle and putting the same in C* .... please help me what should i tweek ? below is my cassandra config

Comment: ,spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=2
spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows=1

Comment: can we pass the C* args in eclipse as VM args ? if so how ??sample plz